# Bubble Sort Implementation in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have implemented a Bubble Sort. It works well. But if you think something needs to be improved, say it. This code was tested in Python 3.7.4.

```
def bubble_sort(nums):

    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        for j in range(0,len(nums)-1-i,1):
            if nums[j] > nums[j+1]:
                swap(nums, j, j+1)

    return nums

def swap(nums, i, j):
    temp = nums[i]
    nums[i] = nums[j]
    nums[j] = temp

if __name__ == "__main__":

   a = [0,0,0,-1,-0,1,2,3,2,1]
   print(bubble_sort(a))
```

Comment: Also you have to be aware that you modify the `a` list - this may not be intended. You might want to copy a list or create a new one and fill with results. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Unnecessary Function

Your `swap` function is unnecessary. Simply replace the function call with this line:

```
nums[j], nums[j + 1] = nums[j + 1], nums[j]
```

This does the swapping for you.

## Spacing

There should be spaces between values in lists

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

between numbers/strings and operators

```
if nums[j] > nums[j + 1]
```

and between parameters in a function call

```
for j in range(0, len(nums) - 1 - i, 1):
```

## Type Hints

Your function header can look like this:

```
from typing import List, Union

def bubble_sort(nums: List[Union[int, float]]) -> List[Union[int, float]]:
```

What this says is that the function accepts a list of integers/floats, and returns a list of integers/floats. It adds another layer of descriptiveness to your code.

## Docstrings

You should include a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) at the beginning of every class/method/module you write. This allows you to describe in words what your code is doing.

```
def bubble_sort(nums: List[Union[int, float]]) -> List[Union[int, float]]:
    """
    A bubble sort algorithm, etc etc etc

    :param nums -> List: A list of integers/floats to sort

    :return List: The sorted list of integers/floats, from smallest -> biggest
    """
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to *Linny*'s answer, one can also optimize the bubble sort algorithm like this:

```
def bubble_sort(nums):  # sorry that I am too lazy to include type hints here :)
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
        found = False
        for j in range(len(nums) - 1 - i):  # start == 0 and step == 1 are unnecessary
            if nums[j] > nums[j + 1]:
                nums[j], nums[j + 1] = nums[j + 1], nums[j]
                found = True  # it means that there is at least a swap
        if not found:  # if there is no swap it means that there is no need to go for next value of i
            break

    return nums
```

Hope it helps.